# Why conjure-up (and not apt) for Kubernetes on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I would like to know what is the rational for the use of conjure-up on
Ubuntu to install Kubernetes?

As far as I know there are Debian packages for Kubernetes.

As a long-time Debian and Ubuntu user I am a bit puzzled on why to
have to use a system that is outside the outstanding dpkg/apt system.

I think I am going to test Kubernetes inside a docker container or a VM,
because I am afraid to pollute the package space of a machine by using
a parallel system to apt...

But I still wonder what is the rationale for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The most important reason to do something like this is to have a more current version of a software product then what's available in the distro repos.

  In production use, you will use LTS versions or things like RHEL/CentOS, with new releases every 2-4 years. For fast moving products like Kubernetes, this is a very long time, but having outside systems manipulate the system is also the strongest reason NOT to use these tools, as they are not necessarily well tested in the environment you want to run them in.
- Also important is the fact that many modern systems are crazy complex with a ton of dependencies and really complicated configuration processes to make all the parts play together nicely. This might be easier to do with other tools than RPM or deb packages (which you would have to replicate for every target system). This is likely a very important reason for Kubernetes. For me, this is another reason to dislike this as "run this puppet script to install our tool", then seeing it do tons of stuff for the next 30min doesn't give me a lot of confidence as I have no frakking clue what is happening and what's really running on my box afterwards.
- Another reason might be to get around quirks in the specific packages or packaging system by the OS vendor.
- Lastly, there is a mixture of "Not invented here", laziness and lack of manpower that might motivate vendors to use their own system instead of providing properly build packages for popular distros.

But in the end, you have to ask the vendor in question why they choose to do what they did of course.